# For Loop only shows last item

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a for loop and it shows the last item. I would like get all items and use as parameters for stored proc. Is there a basic reason, why it would only display the last item?

```
Dim Flipper As String
For x As Integer = 0 To EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles().Count - 1
        Flipper = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name

    Next

Stored Proc:
Select * From myTable Inner Join myOtherTalbe ON myTable.Id = myOtherTable.Id Where RoleId = @RoleId

VB CodeBehind:
Dim strConnection As String = "myDataSource"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("mainForumA", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'params here if needed
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RoleId", Flippers))
        con.Open()
        Dim ds = New DataSet()
        Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)

        cdcatalog.DataSource = ds
        cdcatalog.DataBind()
        con.Close()
```

That will be fine if I only have one Role, but if there are multiple Roles, I need:

```
Select * From myTable Inner Join myOtherTalbe ON myTable.Id = myOtherTable.Id Where RoleId = @RoleId1 Or RoleId = @RoleId2, etc
```

Comment: Cause you overwrite the `Flipper` object with each iteration.

Comment: Each iteration of the loop you're reassigning Flipper without doing anything with the value.

Comment: How do I get each value as an individual string? I don't really want the ListBox, I just want each value as a string separately if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma separated string and use the `In` operator in the sql text.

```
Dim Flippers As New List(Of String)
For x As Integer = 0 To EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles().Count - 1
    Flippers.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name)
Next
Dim values As String = String.Join(Flippers.ToArray, ",") 

Dim sqlText = "Select * From table Where Role In (" & values & ")"
```

Comment: that is awesome and how do i retrieve each value?

Comment: By there index in the collection. How do you need to use them?

Comment: i need to use each as a variable in SQL statement. So I need to know how many there are and: select * from myTable where Role = " & Flippers1 & " Or Role = " & Flippers2 & ", etc, depending on how many are returned

Comment: Ok, you're going to hate me, but its actually a stored proc, so I need to set the values as parameter @role...AND Flippers.ToArray gives error values of array cannot be converted to string.

Comment: Can the parameter be the csv string or is it an array of string? I don't hate you yet, but do include all the requirements when you post, then we are not do this kind of dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to that...cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Role", FlippersValue(s)))

Comment: Can you show the stored procedure in the post and maybe reword what your trying to do?

Comment: I feel we answered your original question and this thread needs to be assigned an answer. Then post the problem with the stored procedure since it is totally different than the original problem.

Comment: Well I changed my question, now you want me to close it and ask a new one...i can do that..you are right you did answer the original question

Comment: Well that was a thought since we were changing in such a radical path, and you could add some other database gurus with some other tags to get a better answer on that part, but whatever you think now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36601/discussion-between-dona-and-mlg74)

Answer (score 0):

As the reply above said, you are not doing anything with Flipper.  You can try adding the names to a list and then binding that.  Also I would store the CustomerRoles in a list instead of resolving IWorkContext each time. It will help you with readability and possibly performance.

```
 Dim Flipper As String
    Dim names As New List(Of String)
    For x As Integer = 0 To EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles().Count - 1
            Flipper = EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name
            names.Add(Flipper)
        Next

    ListView1.DataSource = names
    ListView1.DataBind()
```